# accessing list elements in python

Tags: python, list

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import ZBarSymbol
# Look for just qrcode
decode(Image.open('pyzbar/tests/qrcode.png'), symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
[
    Decoded(
        data=b'Thalassiodracon', type='QRCODE',
        rect=Rect(left=27, top=27, width=145, height=145),
        polygon=[
            Point(x=27, y=27), Point(x=27, y=172), Point(x=172, y=172),
            Point(x=172, y=27)
        ]
    )
]
```

I only want the data field from decode function.
I am new to python and programing in general so cant figure out to do so.

```
info=decode(img, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
print(info)
```

This displays the whole list.

Comment: check for `None` *always* using the `is` operator or `is not` operator, never the `==` operator. i know that's beside the point. as for speeding the code up, there might not be much you can do, unless you investigate the options of the zbar library. consult its documentation. likely you can restrict to only QR codes, no other types. you can check if OpenCV's QR code decoding runs faster

Comment: I do apologize on completely changing the topic ,I figured out the above approach makes it work a bit faster.

Comment: Did you try `decode(img, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])['data']`?

Comment: (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str)   got this error.

Comment: @accdias ,I do apologize for the formatting

Comment: `info[0]` is the first element in the list.

Comment: I didn't notice the function returns a list. Try this instead `decode(img, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])[0]['data']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decode` returns a list of `Decoded` objects.

If you are only interested in the first object, then `info[0].data` will do the trick.

Comment: howere , the output is **b'Thalassiodracon'** .i want the raw text only without b'  '.the desired output is Thalassiodracon

Comment: @HamzaShah  `b"Thalassiodracon".decode()`